# How to compare objects with different types?

Tags: java

In the below program, `DList1` is a list abstraction.

I would like to run some unit test cases in main() function of `DList1` class.

To be specific,

In `main()` method at `Line 105`, `l.head.item != 9` , gives compile error: `Incompatible operand types Object and int`.

At compile time, value `9` is of primitive type `int` and `l.head.item` is of type `class Object`.

At run time, `l.head.item` will be of type `class Integer`. Am not sure about the type of value `9`.

```
/* DList1.java */

/**
 *  A DList1 is a mutable doubly-linked list.  (No sentinel, not
 *  circularly linked.)
 */

public class DList1 {

  /**
   *  head references the first node.
   *  tail references the last node.
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
   */

  protected DListNode1 head;
  protected DListNode1 tail;
  protected long size;

  /* DList1 invariants:
   *  1)  head.prev == null.
   *  2)  tail.next == null.
   *  3)  For any DListNode1 x in a DList, if x.next == y and x.next != null,
   *      then y.prev == x.
   *  4)  For any DListNode1 x in a DList, if x.prev == y and x.prev != null,
   *      then y.next == x.
   *  5)  The tail can be accessed from the head by a sequence of "next"
   *      references.
   *  6)  size is the number of DListNode1s that can be accessed from the
   *      head by a sequence of "next" references.
   */

  /**
   *  DList1() constructor for an empty DList1.
   */
  public DList1() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.size = 0;
  }


  /**
   *  insertFront() inserts an item at the front of a DList1.
   */
  public void insertFront(Object item) {
      if(this.head == null){
          this.head = new DListNode1(item);
          this.tail = this.head;
      }else{
          DListNode1 newNode = new DListNode1(item);
          newNode.next = this.head;
          this.head.prev = newNode;
          this.head = newNode;
      }
      this.size++;
  }

  /**
   *  removeFront() removes the first item (and node) from a DList1.  If the
   *  list is empty, do nothing.
   */
  public void removeFront() {
      if(this.size == 0){
          return;
      }else if(size ==1){
          this.head = null;
          this.tail = null;
      }else{
          this.head.next.prev = null;
          this.head = this.head.next;
      }
  }

  /**
   *  toString() returns a String representation of this DList.
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THIS METHOD.
   *
   *  @return a String representation of this DList.
   */
  public String toString() {
    String result = "[  ";
    DListNode1 current = head;
    while (current != null) {
      result = result + current.item + "  ";
      current = current.next;
    }
    return result + "]";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING CODE.

    DList1 l = new DList1();
    System.out.println("### TESTING insertFront ###\nEmpty list is " + l);

    l.insertFront(9);
    System.out.println("\nInserting 9 at front.\nList with 9 is " + l);
    if (l.head == null) {
      System.out.println("head is null.");
    } else {
        if (l.head.item != 9) { //Line 105
            System.out.println("head.item is wrong.");
        }
        if (l.head.prev != null) {
            System.out.println("head.prev is wrong.");
        }
    }
    if (l.tail == null) {
      System.out.println("tail is null.");
    } else {
      /*if (l.tail.item != 9) {
        System.out.println("tail.item is wrong.");
      }
      if (l.tail.next != null) {
        System.out.println("tail.next is wrong.");
      }*/
    }
    if (l.size != 1) {
      System.out.println("size is wrong.");
    }

    l.insertFront(8);
    System.out.println("\nInserting 8 at front.\nList with 8 and 9 is " + l);
    if (l.head == null) {
      System.out.println("head is null.");
    } else {
      /*if (l.head.item != 8) {
        System.out.println("head.item is wrong.");
      }*/
      if (l.head.prev != null) {
        System.out.println("head.prev is wrong.");
      }
      if (l.head.next != l.tail) {
        System.out.println("head.next is wrong.");
      }
    }
    if (l.tail == null) {
      System.out.println("tail is null.");
    } else {
      if (l.tail.next != null) {
        System.out.println("tail.next is wrong.");
      }
      if (l.tail.prev != l.head) {
        System.out.println("tail.prev is wrong.");
      }
    }
    if (l.size != 2) {
      System.out.println("size is wrong.");
    }

  }

}
```

---

```
/* DListNode1.java */

/**
 *  A DListNode1 is a node in a DList1 (doubly-linked list).
 */

class DListNode1 {

  /**
   *  item references the item stored in the current node.
   *  prev references the previous node in the DList.
   *  next references the next node in the DList.
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
   */

  Object item;
  DListNode1 prev;
  DListNode1 next;

  /**
   *  DListNode1() constructor.
   */
  DListNode1() {
    this.item = null;
    this.prev = null;
    this.next = null;
  }

  DListNode1(Object item) {
    this.item = item;
    this.prev = null;
    this.next = null;
  }
}
```

---

My question:

How can i make types compatible both at compile time and run time and let the value get compared in `Line 105`? What is run time type of value `9`?

Comment: cast to Integer, and then !l.item.head.equals(9)

Comment: @sscnapoli1926 little typo in your update `head.item`. what about my second part of query?

Comment: if you refer to "!" it'not a typo, it's the negation operator! anyway, if you need to decide the type of item at runtime, the only way to do it is to replace Object fields with generics. If "item" can be an instance of a your class, you have to provide an equals() override, and the game is done

Comment: `item.head` is a typo

Comment: @sscnapoli1926  Does changing `DListNode1` to `DListNode1<T>` and changing `DList1` to `DList1<T>` and changing corresponding method declarations, should resolve this problem? i would like to chat with you on this, as i see some issues on the same.

Comment: you're right! in this way, you can implement a list of generic objects. You set the object type when you instatiate DList, which "passes" the type argument to DListNodes when they are created

Comment: @sscnapoli1926 - Generics don't allow you to "decide the type of item at runtime".  Rather, they allow you to use the same class for different parameter types (ie, in different places in your code) without having to do explicit casts.  (The casts are performed implicitly by the compiler.)

Comment: @HotLicks i did not get your statement: `use the same class for different parameter types`, Can you refer my example in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192821/how-to-use-java-generics-to-avoid-casting)?

Comment: @HotLicks yeah but you can set the parameter type when the object is instantiated...you can do something like if(youWantIntList){ dlist = new DList<Integer>();} this is what i mean

Comment: @sscnapoli1926 - But then you have to declare `dlist` to be `DList<Integer>` -- the type is decided at compile time.

Comment: @HotLicks ok, this is obvious, shall we say that type is decided at object instantiation, but you can decide which object use at runtime, hope to be more clear

Comment: The type is decided when you write the code that instantiates the object.  With pretty much any scheme you can, with `if`, `switch`, or whatever, decide which specific code path to follow and hence which object class to instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use a type cast before the comparision: `(int)l.head.item != 9`(it works in Java 7 and later, in older versions you can use `(Integer)l.head.item`).
2. If you list is supposed to be homogeneous, using generics is a good idea.

Comment: What is run time type of value `9`

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, the compiler isn't able to compare a primitive `int` with an `Object`. One way around this is to use the `Integer` wrapper class:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(9).equals(l.head.item)) { //Line 105
```